# Are German university of applied sciences (Fachhochschule) Bachelor degrees recognized in US UK NZ or Australia?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, united-states, undergraduate, germany

I'm a prospective student looking to apply for an electrical engineering course (in English) at Karlsrhuhe, Rhine-Waal and Ravensburg-Weingarten universities of applied sciences.

After doing a little research, I couldn't find any of these unis in international rankings. Acually I couldn't find any applied sciences unis at all. Will this be a problem as I intend to do MBA or M.Eng in the US/UK?

German law says that universities and universities of applied sciences bachelor degrees are equal, but are the latter recognized internationally and are these BSC degrees considered degrees outside Germany?

Comment: For the US, there is no standard notion of 'recognized in the US' for foreign degrees.  Each university makes its own decisions.

Comment: You'd best ask the MBA or M.Eng programs you are interested in about their opinions.  I am pretty sure that at least in the US, Australia, and New Zealand each degree type, even within a university, will be assessed separately by a university admissions office.  If you need a visa, there might be a second assessment with that visa.  In most places German degrees are viewed favorably.

Comment: While I  have heard of a Fachhochschule, I'd guess most academics have not.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist - well, I've heard of them, but could not give a succinct summary of how they differ from various other German institutions. But to a European, perhaps the difference between the University of California and California State systems might be equally opaque...

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist The name is no longer used officially - these days, those are "university of applied science", or some German version thereof (usually using "Hochschule" rather than "Universität", which historically was the name for technical universities, like the former name of TU Munich, or still at RWTH Aachen).

Comment: As an example, UCLA for a professional master's degree in engineering (1 yr), explicitly says that ["Holders of the Vordiplom, Zwischenprüfung, Bachelor/Bakkalaureus, or a diploma from a fachhochschule are not considered for graduate admission."](https://grad.ucla.edu/admissions/required-academic-records/)

Answer (score -1):

We use scoring tables for scholarships. The problem in Australia is that you will not receive extra  'prestigious university' points when applying for a PhD scholarship. [obvs I am at a university that thinks of itself as prestigious, even if I object to this!] But if you get high marks and good references, those will certainly count.   Do not know about Masters level admissions in US/UK, I suspect the UK will not care.

There are many professors who got first degrees or non-degrees from technical universities, colleges, polytechnics, etc.